# Is it possible to create HA cluster on MacOS Catalina?

Tags: mac-osx, high-availability, failovercluster, operating-system

I couldn't find a documentation on configuring HA on Mac OS (Catalina). There's an application called Mac OS Server but the documentation doesn't talk anything about HA rather it looks to be an application to manage multiple devices.

I'm planning to create a HA cluster between two MacPro (2013) loaded on a Sonnet RackMac Pro. After a long search I reached http://preserve.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.23/23.03/OSXFailover-Part1/index.html however it is a writing back from 2006 which I believe was when there were Server OS from Apple.

The question I have here is, Can I create an HA anymore on newer versions of MacOS ? If Yes, is it necessary to configure thunderbolt port to setup HA as per this documentation as discussed in the above link (though that was written before MacPro-2013 was released) or I can just depend over ethernet adapters on both MacPro to complete the project.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do.

Comment: What do you think HA is? Like what do you actually want out of the HA setup?